# Why spark executor receives SIGTERM?

Tags: apache-spark, signals

I am using Spark API (Spark core API, not Stream,SQL etc.)
I often see this kind of error in spark dumped log:
Spark environment: 1.3.1  yarn-client

```
ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

1. Who triggers SIGTERM. YARN,Spark or myself?
2. Will this signal terminate Spark Executor? If not, wow will it affect spark program.

I do press Ctrl+c,  but that whould be SIGINT. If YARN kill executor, that would be SIGKILL.

Comment: Most times it is YARN. Check your node manager logs for that particular time. Sometimes due to OOM YARN kills the container.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely find the reason in yarn logs. If you activated log aggregation, you can type

`yarn logs -applicationId [app_id]`

and lookup for exceptions.

Comment: I looked through the logs and didn't see any exceptions. It all seemed pretty normal, then just got a SIGTERM and this `ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend` and the whole spark application shut down early.